# How to cascade validation in a custom validator?

Tags: java, spring, validation

In a Spring project (4.3.14.RELEASE) I need to validate `Map<String, List<InnerObj>> map` in the MVC layer.

For this purpose I wrote a custom validator

```
public class MapValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidMap, Map<String, List<InnerObj>>> {

@Override
public boolean isValid(final Map<String, List<InnerObj>> map,
                       final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (map == null || map.size() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // iterations over all objects and validation

    return true;
}
```

and annotation

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = MapValidator.class)
public @interface ValidMap {
    String message() default "valid.map";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

How to force the validation to propagate (something like `@Valid`) to the inner object (`List` and `InnerObj`) from my validator?

Comment: What prevents you from using `@Valid`?

Comment: @Valid not working with collections in map

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you can inject the Spring-configured `Validator` into your `MapValidator` and call its `validate` method on list elements. You'll need, however, to integrate the resulting `Set<ConstraintViolation<ISoftBetFRBCoinDTO>>` into the `ConstraintValidatorContext` argument somehow.

This approach seems to be an overkill.

Actually, Bean Validation does support validating collection elements via `@Valid` for method arguments:

```java
public void method(Map<String, List<@Valid Address>> addressMap) {
```

This usage of `@Valid` is called *method validation* in the Bean Validation specification.

It's just in order to activate method validation in Spring, you have to annotate the containing class with Spring's `@Validated` annotation:

```java
@RestController
@Validated
public class HelloWorldController {
    
    @PostMapping("/hello")
    public Map<String, List<Address>> helloWorld(@RequestBody Map<String, List<@Valid Address>> addressMap) {
        return addressMap;
    }
}
```

[From Spring documentation:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#validation-beanvalidation)

> To be eligible for Spring-driven method validation, all target classes need to be annotated with Spring’s `@Validated` annotation, which can optionally also declare the validation groups to use. See [`MethodValidationPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.15/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationPostProcessor.html) for setup details with the Hibernate Validator and Bean Validation 1.1 providers.

See also the linked javadoc of `MethodValidationPostProcessor`.